# Reading Json file obtained from URI - Marklogic

Tags: java, jackson, marklogic

I need to apply patch on Json document after comparing if values are needed to be updated or not.
I have DocumentRecord object(documentRecord) of json document. How can I read contents of Json document. Using documentRecord I have uri of document also

URI is :
     /employee/emp1.json
Salary info is under below tag:
     /employee/YearlySalary/salary
This json file contains name and salary info. Now I need to read value of salary tag from this file.I amble to get below:

```
JacksonHandle content = documentRecord.getContent(new JacksonHandle());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a DocumentRecord with the full document content, there's no reason to use patch.  Just modify the document locally and write it back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To read and modify the contents of the JSON document, get the [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) object using JacksonHandle.get().  For example, given json doc

```
{"objA":[
  {"objB":{"propertyName":"value1"}},
  {"objC":{"propertyName":"value2"}}
]}
```

You could change the value of the first propertyName like so:

```
JsonNode objB = content.get().path("objA").path(0).path("objB");
if ( objB instanceof ObjectNode ) {
  ((ObjectNode) objB).put("propertyName", "newValue");
}
```

Then you could write that back to the db like so:

```
documentManager.write(uri, new JacksonHandle(content));
```